# Keep edge attributes during DFS in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx, depth-first-search, nomachine-nx

I have a `DiGraph` where all the edges have a `size` attribute. However, when I call `G_dfs = nx.dfs_tree(G, source='root')` the `size` attribute is no longer accessible.

Is there a straightforward way to keep the `size` attribute even after the DFS?